# Loading payment methods goes to 504 error on admin side

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, payment-methods

I am trying to load payment option on admin side on magento but it goes to `504 timeout error`.I enabled the logs but didn't get any issue there.Other settings on admin side are working fine.What could be the reason that payment method link not loading ? Thanks i tried by enable the error reporting and logs but didn't get any error on logs.

Comment: how long it takes?  you have to increase php timouts

Comment: @MagenX it loading untill goes to 504 error.Means not loading payment methods.other settings work fine.i have increase the limits but no luck